# toggle button to switch between two tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap to display 2 tabs like so:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
 <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CLient</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Pro</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" style="width:100%;">
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">Client Dashboard</div>
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">Pro Dashboard</div>
</div>
```

Instead of the nav-tabs, I would like a toggle button to switch between them like this one:
http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically select the tab you want to be active with the bootstrap jQuery plugin. So add a click handler to the switch toggle button and select the tab based on the state of the toggle button.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs